# Is there a method to transform values of root key element to string for JSON?

Tags: json, bash, shell, command, transform

I have JSON file dumps and I need to push them into database. Table structure and everything is ready but I need to transform JSON to its equivalent table structure by converting the values of root-level keys into String irrespective of what is present in value ie integers, floats, strings, arrays of json or json objects.

Example to illustrate it.

```json
{
  "k1": 10,
  "k2": "KEY2",
  "k3": [],
  "k4": -55.6,
  "k6": { "k7": 1, "k8": [{ "k9": "true", "k10": "false" }] },
  "k11": "THIS IS VERY LONG MESSAGE OF CHARACTERS UPTO 1024 BYTES"
}
```

and transformed JSON required as.

```json
{
  "k1": "10",
  "k2": "KEY2",
  "k3": "[]",
  "k4": "-55.6",
  "k6": "{ "k7": 1, "k8": [{ "k9": "true", "k10": "false" }] }",
  "k11": "THIS IS VERY LONG MESSAGE OF CHARACTERS UPTO 1024 BYTES"
}
```

ie double qoutes around everything except string not touching the children of root-level values.

If a bash compatible code is available then it is very welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jq` tool can be put to good use here, if that's available to you:

```
$ jq 'map_values(if type == "number" then tostring else . end)' data.json
{
  "k1": "10",
  "k2": "KEY2",
  "k3": [],
  "k4": "-55.6",
  "k6": {
    "k7": 1,
    "k8": [
      {
        "k9": "true",
        "k10": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  "k11": "THIS IS VERY LONG MESSAGE OF CHARACTERS UPTO 1024 BYTES"
}
```

If you *do* want to make integers deeper in the structure into strings, there is also:

```
$ jq 'walk(if type == "number" then tostring else . end)' data.json
{
  "k1": "10",
  "k2": "KEY2",
  "k3": [],
  "k4": "-55.6",
  "k6": {
    "k7": "1",
    "k8": [
      {
        "k9": "true",
        "k10": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  "k11": "THIS IS VERY LONG MESSAGE OF CHARACTERS UPTO 1024 BYTES"
}
```

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/

Comment: Thank you! It works! It also worked for files which contained JSON on each row with \n as line delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

```
jq 'map_values(if type == "number" or type == "array" or type == "object" then tostring else . end)' input_json|sed 's/\\"/"/g'
{
  "k1": "10",
  "k2": "KEY2",
  "k3": "[]",
  "k4": "-55.6",
  "k6": "{"k7":1,"k8":[{"k9":"true","k10":"false"}]}",
  "k11": "THIS IS VERY LONG MESSAGE OF CHARACTERS UPTO 1024 BYTES"
}
```